# Вытягивание сайтов из интернета автоматически

Tags: скрипт

Вытягивание сайтов из интернета автоматически
Со всего интернета как это сделать?
На подобии как у поисковиков которые сами вытягивают сайты из интернета

и есть ли такие поисковики в открытом доступе?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте стягивать сайты curl например, парсить ссылки и стягивать дальше. Я думаю google так работает)